# Is there an easy way to suppress the outer "{" .. "}" when writing JSON from a boost property_tree?

Tags: c++, json, boost

the boost::property_tree::write_json function to write a property_tree out as JSON always places the contents inside a set of outer delimiters "{ ... }

ie:

```
{
    "field": "value",
    "field2": "value"
}
```

I want to get just the contents inside the delimiters and not the leading "{" and trailing "}"

Is there a reasonable way to do this other than writing it into a separate buffer, chopping them off and the writing that buffer out ?

Comment: Don't the outer curly braces make it correct JSON?

Comment: Yes they do - this is part of wanting to factor out parts of the COMPOSITION of a final piece of 100% correct json, the wrapping {} to be added later.

as in:

piece1 = "\"a\":1, \"b\":2";
piece1 = "\"c\":1, \"d\":2";


whole thing = "{" + piece1 + "," + piece2 + "}";

Yes one can merge maps and then serialize from a final map, but in this case I know that every tuple in the total is unique.